# Seek Bar funcationality with custom ui elements

Tags: android, seekbar

am looking to create a customs slider component with the functionality of s seek bar.

I have been following this tutorial
http://www.androidenea.com/2011/10/creating-custom-view-part-1-graphics.html

however, I wish to use my own graphics which aren't .9.png graphics.  I also need to resize the seek bar and the slider.

If anyone can help on this I'd greatly appreciate it.  I have it to a stage where I have it resized and the graphics are changed however, when I use my finger to slide upwards I need to slide to the top of the screen in order for my seebar to reach the top of the frame.

Please any help is appreciated, this is what I've implemented so far:

```
package com.enea.training.customview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomSlider extends View {
    interface CustomSliderPositionListener {
        void onPositionChange(float newPosition);
    }

    private final Drawable               mIndicator;
    private final Drawable               mBackground;
    private float                        mMin;
    private float                        mMax;
    private float                        mPosition;
    private Rect                         mViewRect;
    private int                          mIndicatorOffset;
    private int                          mIndicatorMaxPos;
    private int                          mIndicatorMinPos;
    private CustomSliderPositionListener mPositionListener;
    private boolean                      mIsVertical;

    public CustomSlider(final Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public CustomSlider(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomSlider(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
                        final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.CustomSlider);
        final int vertical = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomSlider_orientation, 0);
        mIsVertical = (vertical != 0);

        final float max = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CustomSlider_max, 1.0f);
        final float min = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CustomSlider_min, -1.0f);
        setMinMax(min, max);

        final Resources res = context.getResources();
        if (mIsVertical) {
            mIndicator = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.beer_with_arrows);
            mBackground = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.glass);
        } else {
            mIndicator = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.indicator_horizontal);
            mBackground = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.background_horizontal);
        }

        mPosition =(mMax - 1) ;/// 2 + mMin;
        mPositionListener = null;
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
                final float pos;
                if (mIsVertical) {
                    float divisor = mIndicatorMinPos-mIndicatorMaxPos;
                    pos = (mMax - ((mMax - mMin) / divisor)
                            * event.getY());
                } else {
                    pos = (mMin + ((mMax - mMin) / (mIndicatorMaxPos - mIndicatorMinPos))
                            * event.getX());
                }
                setPosition(pos);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        if (mViewRect == null) {
            mViewRect = new Rect();
            mViewRect.set(20,20,20,20);
            getDrawingRect(mViewRect);
            if (mIsVertical) {
                mIndicatorOffset = mIndicator.getIntrinsicHeight();
                mIndicatorMaxPos = mViewRect.top + mIndicatorOffset;
                mIndicatorMinPos = mViewRect.bottom - mIndicatorOffset;
            } else {
                mIndicatorOffset = mIndicator.getIntrinsicWidth();
                mIndicatorMaxPos = mViewRect.right - mIndicatorOffset;
                mIndicatorMinPos = mViewRect.left + mIndicatorOffset;
            }
            mBackground.setBounds(mViewRect.left, mViewRect.top, mViewRect.right,
                    mViewRect.bottom);
        }

        final float pos;
        final int left;
        final int right;
        final int top;
        final int bottom;
        if (mIsVertical) {
            pos = mIndicatorMaxPos
                    + ((mIndicatorMinPos - mIndicatorMaxPos) / (mMax - mMin))
                    * (mMax - mPosition);
            left = mViewRect.centerX() - (mIndicator.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2);
            top = (int) pos - (mBackground.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2);
        } else {
            pos = mIndicatorMinPos
                    + ((mIndicatorMaxPos - mIndicatorMinPos) / (mMax - mMin))
                    * (mPosition - mMin);
            left = (int) pos - (mIndicator.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2);
            top = mViewRect.centerY() - (mIndicator.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2);
        }
        right = left + mIndicator.getIntrinsicWidth();
        bottom = top + mIndicator.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mIndicator.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mIndicator.draw(canvas);
        mBackground.draw(canvas);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec,
                             final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mIsVertical) {
            int desiredWidth = 100;
            int desiredHeight = 100;

            int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
            int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            int width;
            int height;

            //Measure Width
            if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                //Must be this size
                width = widthSize;
            } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                //Can't be bigger than...
                width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
            } else {
                //Be whatever you want
                width = desiredWidth;
            }

            //Measure Height
            if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                //Must be this size
                height = heightSize;
            } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                //Can't be bigger than...
                height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
            } else {
                //Be whatever you want
                height = desiredHeight;
            }

            //MUST CALL THIS
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);


            //setMeasuredDimension(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
            //  setMeasuredDimension(mIndicator.getIntrinsicWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
        } else {
            setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), mBackground.getIntrinsicHeight());
        }
    }

    public float getMin() {
        return mMin;
    }

    public float getMax() {
        return mMax;
    }

    public float getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }

    public void setPosition(float position) {
        position = within(position, mMin, mMax);
        if (position != mPosition) {
            mPosition = position;
            invalidate();
            if (mPositionListener != null) {
                mPositionListener.onPositionChange(mPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    private static float within(float position, final float min, final float max) {
        if (position < min) {
            position = min;
        }
        if (position > max) {
            position = max;
        }
        return position;
    }

    public void setMinMax(final float min, final float max) {
        if ((min != mMin) || (max != mMax)) {
            if (min > max) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "setMinMax: min must be smaller than max.");
            }
            mMin = min;
            mMax = max;
            setPosition(mPosition);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void setPositionListener(final CustomSliderPositionListener listener) {
        mPositionListener = listener;
    }
}
```

****EDIT****

So below  I have done up a rough pic to show what I'm trying to do.  So my custom view includes the slider, and frame (background and indicator).  The slider (indicator) is dragged by user up and down inside the red background..

I would apprecaite any help and thank you for your help so far...

[image]I

Comment: hi, if anyone needs anymore info please don't hesitate to ask, i can't approve edits as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Using non-ninepatch graphics is going to be a pain.

Comment: really?  Can I ask how so?  When it comes to this area I am completely new to it

Comment: if I use Draw 9-patch in the sdk folder to convert?  If so will this make things easier?

Comment: Yes that would make it much easier, it makes sure the image quality is not lost when it is resized

Comment: ok, but that will be the only benefit to having 9 patch files?  Any ideas on my other problem?